# unable to run a simple eureka server application

Tags: tomcat, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

[This is a ss of cloud compatibility with springboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyYxA.png)
**This is my pomxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**and this is my application.properties**

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false 
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**And my main file**

```
package com.example.eurekaserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

**when i change the spring cloud version to "<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>"**

```
2023-06-14 17:06:49.306  INFO 6288 --- [ main] c.e.e.EurekaServerApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-06-14 17:06:49.964  WARN 6288 --- [  main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2023-06-14 17:06:50.260  INFO 6288 --- [  main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=70732503-b5f4-38d3-8aa5-7fe93f9c0d3b
2023-06-14 17:06:50.375  INFO 6288 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$89a7f8be] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-06-14 17:06:50.785  INFO 6288 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-14 17:06:50.815  INFO 6288 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-14 17:06:50.816  INFO 6288 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2023-06-14 17:06:50.834  INFO 6288 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\asaph\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/asaph/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/asaph/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\asaph\node_modules\@angular\cli;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\bin;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;;.]
2023-06-14 17:06:50.998  INFO 6288 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-14 17:06:50.998  INFO 6288 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1674 ms
2023-06-14 17:06:51.129  WARN 6288 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2023-06-14 17:06:51.129  INFO 6288 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2023-06-14 17:06:51.140  INFO 6288 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@72b0a004
2023-06-14 17:06:52.705  INFO 6288 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2023-06-14 17:06:52.992  INFO 6288 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2023-06-14 17:06:53.059  INFO 6288 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2023-06-14 17:06:53.061  INFO 6288 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2023-06-14 17:06:53.328 ERROR 6288 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [servletContainer]

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:989) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:592) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:514) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:483) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:429) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:396) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.XmlXStream.<init>(XmlXStream.java:51) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.XmlXStream.<clinit>(XmlXStream.java:42) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers$XStreamXml.<init>(CodecWrappers.java:358) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.create(CodecWrappers.java:133) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.getEncoder(CodecWrappers.java:75) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.getEncoder(CodecWrappers.java:66) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.<init>(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.<init>(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:64) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:180) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:159) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:153) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:278) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProviders(ProviderServices.java:151) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:175) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1338) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4511) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.eurekaserver.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @3d680b5a
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:40) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    ... 81 common frames omitted

2023-06-14 17:06:53.331 ERROR 6288 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2023-06-14 17:06:53.332 ERROR 6288 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2023-06-14 17:06:53.339  WARN 6288 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [spring.cloud.inetutils] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.getHostByAddr(Native Method)
 java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByAddress(InetAddress.java:1073)
 java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getHostFromNameService(InetAddress.java:811)
 java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:753)
 java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:725)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
2023-06-14 17:06:53.437  INFO 6288 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-14 17:06:53.440  WARN 6288 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-06-14 17:06:53.453  INFO 6288 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-14 17:06:53.456 ERROR 6288 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.eurekaserver.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

**and with ther version of "<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>" it works but still i am unable to load the eureka server page**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2023-06-14 17:27:26.399  INFO 16024 --- [           main] c.e.e.EurekaServerApplication            : Starting EurekaServerApplication on lafestro with PID 16024 (C:\Users\asaph\Downloads\eureka-server\eureka-server\target\classes started by asaph in C:\Users\asaph\Downloads\eureka-server\eureka-server)
2023-06-14 17:27:26.402  INFO 16024 --- [           main] c.e.e.EurekaServerApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-06-14 17:27:27.923  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2023-06-14 17:27:27.961  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-14 17:27:27.962  INFO 16024 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2023-06-14 17:27:27.975  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\asaph\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/asaph/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/asaph/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_19.0.1.v20221102-1007/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\asaph\node_modules\@angular\cli;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333\bin;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\asaph\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;;.]
2023-06-14 17:27:28.156  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-14 17:27:28.156  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1704 ms
2023-06-14 17:27:28.781  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2023-06-14 17:27:29.233  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-06-14 17:27:29.387  INFO 16024 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-14 17:27:29.390  INFO 16024 --- [           main] c.e.e.EurekaServerApplication            : Started EurekaServerApplication in 4.476 seconds (JVM running for 4.962)
```

**the webpage says**
"Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jun 14 17:17:30 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available"

SO could someone please help me with this.

to summarise the questions
1.Why when greenwich is used i get tomcat embedded server unable to start (how do you resolve it)
2.In the second where the server is running but still the webpage says whitelabel....

Comment: You need to use compatible versions of spring boot and spring cloud. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions#supported-releases or https://start.spring.io

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyYxA.png         This is the image....it says that greenwich is compatible but it doesn't works....could you tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to rerun your service after adding this in your **application.properties**

**eureka.instance.hostname=localhost**

Or you can use latest version of **spring boot 3.1.0**

Comment: thanks but the issue got resolved....i had xertain jar versions not suitable like xtream and others which i got through exceptions (myself heard first time) then i added the compatible jars of those and it worked........frankly i still dont know what purpose those jars served but i couldn't look into it as there are jut too many to know and it seemed better to just do whatever the exception told, add the suitable jar version rather than studying about them. Any further guidance towards on the workings and understandings of the internaL jars  in a doable way is welcomed. thanks anyways !!